# isearch in kmacro-step-edit-macro

Tags: isearch, keyboard-macros

I'm trying to edit a keyboard macro using `kmacro-step-edit-macro`.
The macro starts by isearching for a word.

```
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
binary_function     ;; self-insert-command * 15
RET         ;; newline
```

When stepping through the macro it only searches for the first letter in the word, after which it just inserts the rest into the buffer.
Am I using `kmacro-step-edit-macro` wrong? Is it broken?
I'm using emacs 26.1 on windows.

Comment: I'm also seeing this on linux 27.1.  Looks broken to me.